# I expected the system to report non protocol conformance, but it does not! Why?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-optionals

I am using Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

> I am trying to create a generic function in Swift that will reject its
>   parameter unless such a parameter is Optional.

In the following code, I was **expecting** the system to report **errors** in all calls to `onlyCallableByAnOptable()` made inside `test()`, because none of them provide an **optional** value as a parameter.

However, the system only reports non-protocol conformance if I remove the `Optional` extension that conforms to `Optable`!

Which to me, it means that the system is regarding **any and all** values as `Optional`, regardless!

**Am I doing something wrong?**

*(By the way, the following code used to be working as expected in earlier versions of Swift. I just recently found out that it stopped working, for it was letting a non-`Optional` go through.)*

```
protocol Optable {
    func opt()
}

func onlyCallableByAnOptable<T>( _ value: T) -> T where T: Optable {
    return value
}

// Comment the following line to get the errors 
extension Optional: Optable { func opt() {} }


class TestOptable {
    static func test() 
    {
        let c = UIColor.blue
        let s = "hi"
        let i = Int(1)

        if let o = onlyCallableByAnOptable(c) { print("color \(o)") }
        //^ expected ERROR: Argument type 'UIColor' does not conform to expected type 'Optable'

        if let o = onlyCallableByAnOptable(s) { print("string \(o)") }
        //^ expected ERROR: Argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'Optable'

        if let o = onlyCallableByAnOptable(i) { print("integer \(o)") }
        //^ expected ERROR: Argument type 'Int' does not conform to expected type 'Optable'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've made all `Optional`s conform to `Optable` and you are using the `if let` syntax to unwrap the result of the call to `onlyCallableByAnOptable` (which means the return type must be some kind of `Optional`, which means the parameter must also be that same type of `Optional` because both the parameter and the return type are of type `T` in your generic method), Swift is inferring the types being passed in as `UIColor?`, `String?`, and `Int?` (implicitly wrapping them in `Optional`s) instead of `UIColor`, `String` and `Int`.

Comment: Mmm!... So it has to do with function return type inference!

Comment: I wanted swift to infer the type solely based on the parameter provided not also based on the expected return type (i.e context). Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: You could try changing your function's return type to `T?`, if you always want it to return an optional type, like: `func onlyCallableByAnOptable<T>(_ value: T) -> T? where T: Optable`. Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, though. Doing that, I then get the errors that you would expect (e.g. "global function 'onlyCallableByAnOptable' requires that 'UIColor' conform to 'Optable'", etc.)

Comment: Ok. No worries. If I happen to find a way to do what I wanted, I will then post it here as an added answer.

Comment: I added an answer. What do you think? Am I overcomplicating?

Answer (score 0):

I am the one who posted this question.

> I was trying to create a generic function in Swift that would reject
>   its parameter unless such parameter is an `Optional`.

As *@TylerTheCompiler* pointed out, using my original implementation (in the question), Swift was inferring type `T` (used in `onlyCallableByAnOptable()`), based on the full context of the call, not solely on the type of the value provided as parameter to it, therefore inferring `T` to be an `Optional`.

For the sake of helping others who might be trying to achieve the same as I was, the following is my solution to the problem I had.

All calls to `onlyCallableByAnOptable(...)` now correctly yield errors due to non-protocol conformance.

Errors like: `Argument type 'UIColor' does not conform to expected type 'Optable'`

> If anyone knows of a simpler solution, please do post it as an answer
>   to: [How to create a generic function in Swift that will reject the given parameter unless it is an Optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550468/how-to-create-a-generic-function-in-swift-that-will-reject-the-given-parameter-u).

```
protocol Optable {
    associatedtype OptableType
    func optionalOptable() -> OptableType?
    func opt()
}

func onlyCallableByAnOptable<T>( _ value: T) -> T.OptableType? where T: Optable {
    return value.optionalOptable()
}


extension Optional: Optable {
    typealias OptableType = Wrapped //: Wrapped is the type of the element, as defined in Optional
    func opt() {}
    func optionalOptable() -> OptableType? {
        return self
    }
}


class TestOptable {
    static func test()
    {
        let c = UIColor.blue
        let s = "hi"
        let i = Int(1)

        if let o = onlyCallableByAnOptable(c) {  // ERROR, as was desired.
            print("color \(o)") 
        }
        if let o = onlyCallableByAnOptable(s) {  // ERROR, as was desired.
            print("string \(o)") 
        }
        if let o = onlyCallableByAnOptable(i) {  // ERROR, as was desired.
            print("integer \(o)") 
        }
    }
}
```